# How do I represent an i64 in the u64 domain?

Tags: rust, bit-shift

What is the rusticle way to to represent the an i64 [-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807] into the u64 domain [0, 18446744073709551615]. So for example 0 in i64 is 9223372036854775808 in u64.

Here is what I have done.

```
    let x: i64 = -10;
    let x_transform = ((x as u64) ^ (1 << 63)) & (1 << 63) | (x as u64 & (u64::MAX >> 1));
    let x_original = ((x_transform as i64) ^ (1 << 63)) & (1 << 63) | (x_transform & (u64::MAX >> 1)) as i64;
    
    println!("x_transform {}", x_transform);
    println!("x_original {} {}", x_original, x_original == x);
```

yielding

> x_transform 9223372036854775798

> x_original -10 true

Is there a built in way to do this, because it seems too verbose, and error prone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance view it doesn't really matter how you write it, a quick check on [godbot](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DEArgoKkl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywYgATADZSjgBk8BkwAOXcAI0xiEAB2UgAHVAVCOwYXNw9vPySU2wEgkPCWKJj4q0wbNKECJmICDPdPX0tMa3yGGrqCQrDI6LjLWvrGrJbzbt7i0riASktUE2Jkdg4AejWAagAVAE8EzE3dxeJNtCxNhGjMUk2STdpUJnRNw03MVVYE%2BgA6AFINABBBImCKbKgMTYKACOJjqmAgs02f1iACEAYDNliHpgCJt1Js8D5JMiAMwAEU2AFouBo/qT0UDsTi8aoAPoEYiGBT8YgsMmUohskzEiCqWb0xmY7H0Vlskh4YDBMQCzZComSMUcrkMHkkFgShkY5myo6qgDuXISHNQwtF4slxpluM2AC8LVabWyNRBdoapcz0BFgGBIE7mVjdqRwxH2ZzubyWNGmRGsXGdXq%2BQL6ZSozHma7k9LU%2ByFUrmLQi6m0/LiIrlbRsxT8VXq%2B6czn8TH/Rje7FyRiQWCIZtLUxrUKRZqCRqkVT6dhNlPkWiY2LXgol8TZj8xwkEsFgGznugIFOQCAALKAgAaay8yK8qM2XAlQJRA6BQ/BkL3Xp9BJTnOC6EsSK4Btiqi7laB5GGyCigmexIXted4Pn8T4vkiTCbhqfafsCoI/mqtpTmKICgZIwGkouy4ohBWJQKoG5blRyIAKyLhAXBkk49JOJsPikrMSIYT4mzcbx/GCcJK4CeuOGsY%2B4lIZIKG3mS2Aga%2Bb6Ah%2Bg5ESO6r2hRQHUiBGrgWuCm4duHFcTx/HSUJInKRJjmknxnkyaJsTycxYkSeeV4aQu2muYpeHvv2vZAhsmwAJJUEcixLkoyI%2BBoLBMMEiJ/JltxYMgBjEIchAsflGhDpVJFQpgZV4sEapXHcJgECCBAgBi8XfiO2W5b5z4/MNK4ERw8y0Jw7G8J4HBaKQqCcAASmYeIKCcKyPqSPCkJ1c3jfMADWIDsRo%2BicJIM2aLwi0cLwCggGde1aPMcCwEgaAsAe9BkBQECfd9AzEFwPinaQWAAG54CsABqeCYOaADyByzTtNC0AQ0QPRAETXaQETKsQuycDtn1sIIiMMLQxP7eDmDZUY4i0/gpVVBDmAPbTHyVG1qw7cEmOTbTtB4BEXJEy4WB45yeAsCT418AYwAKHDCPI4w8syIIIhiOwUha/IShqHjuhcPohjGKt%2Biiw9kDzKgCQdJzVICdWbsOwQVL0OztA5jtFRVPYECOKMnhm4EwR9CUAxm7kqQCKHehxx0Uz9DEZsBx0XQjK4TR6Jn1TDD0kfTDHQzdInGdF6n0fp/M61LCsEgTVNV207dmymOYyAvj8oM/BoEm4IQ9wYdtsy8M9B2kMdYNC5dpCzfNt33Y9u3XSJ50cF4bfL5wk8b/M7PECk9iSEAA%3D%3D%3D) shows both the wrapping and the bit shifty versions compile to the same machine code.
But I'd argue the variants with wrapping are way more readable and convey the intent better.

```rust
pub fn wrap_to_u64(x: i64) -> u64 {
    (x as u64).wrapping_add(u64::MAX/2 + 1)
}
pub fn wrap_to_i64(x: u64) -> i64 {
    x.wrapping_sub(u64::MAX/2 + 1) as i64
}
pub fn to_u64(x: i64) -> u64 {
    ((x as u64) ^ (1 << 63)) & (1 << 63) | (x as u64 & (u64::MAX >> 1))
}
pub fn to_i64(x: u64) -> i64 {
    ((x as i64) ^ (1 << 63)) & (1 << 63) | (x & (u64::MAX >> 1)) as i64
}
```

```
example::wrap_to_u64:
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775808
        xor     rax, rdi
        ret

example::wrap_to_i64:
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775808
        xor     rax, rdi
        ret

example::to_u64:
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775808
        xor     rax, rdi
        ret

example::to_i64:
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775808
        xor     rax, rdi
        ret
```

The lesson to learn is that unless you have a very specific optimization probably the compiler will outperform you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to just translate the two's complement representation, rather than use offset-binary:

```rust
let x_transform = u64::from_ne_bytes(x.to_ne_bytes());
let x_original = i64::from_ne_bytes(x_transform.to_ne_bytes());
```

However according to the to the wiki:

> Offset binary may be converted into two's complement by inverting the most significant bit.

So you could do that and use the less error-prone two's complement for the actual translation:

```rust
pub fn convert1(x: i64) -> u64 {
        ((x as u64) ^ (1 << 63)) & (1 << 63) | (x as u64 & (u64::MAX >> 1))
}

pub fn convert3(x: i64) -> u64 {
    // manipulating the bytes in transit requires
    // knowing the MSB, use LE as that's the most
    // commmon by far
    let mut bytes = x.to_le_bytes();
    bytes[7] ^= 0x80;
    u64::from_le_bytes(bytes)
}

pub fn convert4(x: i64) -> u64 {
    u64::from_ne_bytes((x ^ i64::MIN).to_ne_bytes())
}
```

[all produce the exact same x86_64 code](https://godbolt.org/z/q86c3e5ne):

```
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775808
        xor     rax, rdi
        ret
```

Comment: Wait I specifically refreshed before I posted my answer, how did this not show up.

Comment: @cafce25 I'd originally missed that the OP was using offset binary, and thus only posted the initial snippet. When I realised I deleted the answer, after which I gave it a thought, noticed the "undelete" button for the first time, checked the wiki, expanded the comment to actually answer the prompt, and undeleted. You probably posted while my answer was still deleted. Sorry about that.

Comment: Or simply `pub fn convert5 (x: i64) -> u64 { (x as u64) ^ (1 << 63) }` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PdGjErexc)).